# How to get back to Oracle Java after installing OpenJDK

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I've installed Oracle JDK using [this guide](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-install-java-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). Then I accidently installed OpenJDK(tried to prepare PC to build Android). How do I get back to Oracle Java? Can I **keep** OpenJDK, but set Oracle Java as default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to keep both versions without a problem.  I found [a link](http://islandlinux.org/howto/command-switch-java-version-ubuntu) that describes how to switch between Java versions on Ubuntu.

To switch between Java versions:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

To switch better javac (complier) versions:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```